# How do I fix a heavily rusted garburator?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I have an INsinkerator that I never used for years as I hate it.  I tested it out the other day and it no longer works as it appears heavily rusted over due to non-use. I tried the red re-set button, but it wouldn't work. I would hear a low hum and it would pop back out.  I found an allen key and tried turning it from the bottom with no success (seemed super stuck).

Is this fixable?  Is there any way to remove the rust that is safe?  Or am I better off replacing it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's dead, Jim.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the thing. New ones are not excessively expensive.

Attempts at repair are likely to be a futile exercise. The reason is that old disposers often corrode right through the lower portion of the casing and there really is no good way to repair that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use it why replace it?  Just remove it and put a standard drain in.

Comment: Definitely this. Those things are a blight, I tell you! The only people who seem use them are the ones who can't resist feeding them things that have no business being in your plumbing and will just clog your pipes.

Answer (score 0):

DEFINITELY replace it. If you have some extra time on your hands, take this one and fiddle with it until you get it into nice shape again... then keep it for a spare.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I disagree with the other two answers here but in the intereset of exploring all options, try spraying half a can of CorrosionX (or any descent penetrating lubricant spray) down there, let it sit for an hour or two, and then crank it a few revolutions with your allen wrench and see if it breaks up the corrosion. I don't hold out a lot of hope for this option but it's worth the cost of a can of CX to try it. Cheers!

Comment: If the OP has a septic system, they may want to be careful about what chemicals they pour down the drain. I would remove the disposal before trying this.

Comment: Hmmm. That's a good point. I looked up the MSDS(material safety data sheet) on CX and its not exactly a protein shake. If it is the case that you have a septic system you might want to just yard that old garburator out. Thanks Doresoom.

Comment: On the other hand, if the OP has a septic system they may not want to use a garbage disposal anyway...

Comment: Really, nobody should use a garbage disposal.

Comment: Alright, I'll bite. Why the hate? We use a disposal at home, and i can confirm with anecdotal evidence that it's so far been extremely useful. We don't clog the thing with junk, but aren't gentle either. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Especially for septic systems, garbage disposals encourage disposing of things down the drain that have no business entering the septic system - things that generate both the sludge layer and the scum layer far more quickly than normal. A really HEALTHY properly sized septic system, fed only what it SHOULD be fed, requires pumping no more often than about once every twenty years and will never plug the leach field.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest problem with disposals is that anything bigger than plate scrapings will eventually clog up the almost-horizontal waste pipe going from my sink to the main stack, but I'm sure many houses are less vulnerable to that than mine. Anyway, I bought an Insinkerator in '03 that lasted about 11 years (until the base of the grind chamber leaked through  rust holes), during which it froze up a couple of times; each time, I was able to un-stick it with the allen wrench, but it took a lot of back-and-forth. I replaced it with one my neighbor mistakenly thought was bad (the cable had fractured); that eventually started leaking around the casing of the grind chamber and I fixed it with gorilla glue and drywall tape. I intend to try the same thing with my old one; neither one will last forever, but they've both had respectable life spans. Insinkerators seem very prone to rust, they obviously don't use much stainless steel, though mine (unlike my neighbor's) had a plastic grind-chamber casing which has actually held up very well, so an all-plastic model might be an improvement. Before either of these I had a top-of-the-line Sears, which had much more stainless steel, but only lasted 7 years; the nut holding the grinding disk in place (which tended to be permanently rusted tight on the Insinkerators) got loose. I've fixed it with epoxy, but won't know how well it holds until the one I'm using quits for good.

PS: Don't use bleach in these; it eats right through regular steel and isn't kind to either stainless or plastic. I find alternating between hot water and ice cubes gets rid of the stench.